# Javascript redirecionar e setar cookies

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Tenho o seguinte código com `Javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {
      $("#success").css("display", "block"), $('#success').html("Autenticando...");
      $('#info').hide();
      $('.form-group').hide();

      var rootUrl = "<?php echo URL_BASE; ?>";

      var username = $("#username").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();

      $.ajax( {
        method: "POST",
        url: "api/login.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(i) {
          if (i["status"] == "success") {
            $("#error").css("display", "none");
            location.href = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true";
          } else {
            if (i["status"] == "error") {
              $("#error").css("display", "block"), $("#error").html(i["message"]);
              $("#success").css("display", "none"), $("#success").empty();
              $(".form-group").show();
              $("#info").show();
              return false;
            }
          }
        }, error: function (error) { console.log(error); }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

E no meu `PHP`:

```
if (isset($cookies['auth_token'])) {

  Cookies::set('auth_token', $cookies['auth_token']);
  Cookies::set('user', $ttrUsername);
  Cookies::set('pass', $ttrPassword);

  $_SESSION[SITE_NAME . '_SESSION'] = $ttrUsername;

  echo json_encode(array(
            "status"          => "success",
          "message"     => "Autenticação bem sucedida, estamos te redirecionando.",
        ));

} else {
    echo json_encode(
                array(
                    "status" => "error",
                    'message'=> "Não foi possível autenticar com o Twitter.",
                ));
}
```

O Problema que o `Javascript` redireciona mas não leva os Cookies juntos, como resolver isto?

**EDIT 1**

Onde

```
Cookies::set('auth_token', $cookies['auth_token']);
```

É equivalente á:

```
setcookie('auth_token', $cookies['auth_token'], time() + (2 * 3600));
```

Comment: Sim, se eu retirar `location.href = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true";` do meu código javascript os Cookies aparecem, mas se eu deixar ele redireciona sem Cookie criado entendeu?

Comment: continua ainda não setando Cookies na outra página, PS: estou usando url amigável.

Comment: Opa resolvido `setcookie($key, $value, time() + (2 * 3600), '/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No manual do PHP do [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php):

> **Caminho** (path)
>
> O caminho no servidor no qual o cookie estará disponível. Se
>   configurado para '/', o cookie estará disponível em todo o domínio. Se
>   configurado para '/ foo /', o cookie só estará disponível no diretório
>   /foo/ e todos os subdiretórios, como /foo/bar/ do dominio. O
>   valor padrão é o diretório atual no qual o cookie está sendo
>   configurado.

Você pode fazer assim, como você [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217192/javascript-redirecionar-e-setar-cookies?noredirect=1#comment444140_217192):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Value", time()+3600 , '/' );
```

Ou ainda se você quiser disponível no domínio principal e em qualquer subdomínio, forneça o quinto parâmetro como este:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Value", time()+3600 , '/', '.example.com' );
```

Comment: resolvi assim `setcookie($key, $value, time() + (2 * 3600), '/');`, mas estou com outro problema que não consigo resolver, vou abrir outra pergunta

Comment: @WillBB ali só é um exemplo mesmo, o nome você que define.. rsrs

Comment: Mas é igual então vou marcar como resolvido

Comment: Se puder me ajudar também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217231/obter-apenas-uma-parte-da-string-de-cookies