# Obter apenas uma parte da string de Cookies

Tags: php, cookies

Eu tenho o cookie: **twid** que está retornando assim no navegador.

`%22u%3D859186139894337536%22`

Gostaria de pegar apenas isto:

`859186139894337536`

É possível faze-lo em `PHP`.

PS: Estou obtendo `cookies` do Twitter via `cURL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente você deverá usar o [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php) para remover os caracteres de URL da sua string.

```
$var = urldecode("%22u%3D859186139894337536%22");
```

Após isso você poderá usar a função [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) que filtrará sua string e retornará o que você especificar:

```
$var = filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

print_r($var);
```

Comment: Cara vc é de mais... vlw